# Do I have moles?

Tags: pest-control

I know I have voles. I accidentally  planted a small running bamboo ;it has spread all over and makes a great buffet for the voles . I have copperheads which like the voles. I get mounds ( 6 inch diameter, 2 inches high) in the grass; are the mounds from voles or moles ?

Answer (score 7):

Moles live in tunnels rarely to see the sun, voles borrow their tunnels but live like mice above ground mostly.  Moles are very few in number. Extremely territorial.  One or two will aerate and gobble grubs beautifully.  Voles are just fine.  They can cause damage during the winter if you use a thick mulch to protect a woody perennial like roses for example.  The mulch is like a great home and they can chew down to the vascular system and girdle plants within their winter home.

If you've got snakes, leave well enough alone.  You've got the best possible harmony going.  Mounds means moles.  Only one or two are responsible for the mounds.  Those mounds are soil they dug out of the subsurface of your garden...means they are doing you big favors with aeration of the soil and eating the grubs that will cause damage to plants as well as top dressing.  Just knock the hills down.  I've never ever had problems with little mammals.  Ground gophers show their tunneling above ground.  Yet they've never bothered my vegetable garden.  Rats, now they can be pretty destructive but having a cat or two is all that is necessary.

I can't see any animal with the ability to harm bamboo.  Perhaps at the baby stage but that would only help with thinning.

Comment: They eat large white underground rhizomes of the bamboo and there is plenty.

Comment: Sounds like an ideal arrangement! Would love to shoot animals and bamboo there (photos, not a gun).